# How can I find implementations for Kernels/Traits in CGAL?

Tags: c++, templates, cgal

I use CGAL's implementation of EfficientRANSAC to detect cylinders. `CGAL::Shape_detection::Cylinder` has a public member `axis()` which I use [Link](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Shape_detection/classCGAL_1_1Shape__detection_1_1Cylinder.html#ab70ecc08bf20f1557135140c6a8b27cd). This method calls `EfficientRANSACTraits::Construct_point_on_3` and the [documentation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Shape_detection/classEfficientRANSACTraits.html#ab71e35d5be40f9e0f96879f63b5bae52) states:

> Function object type that provides Point_3 operator()(Line_3 l, int i) returning an arbitrary point on l.

From my experience the point does not seem to really be arbitrary, but I struggle to find the place where the calculation is actually done. Searching through the github repo makes me believe that the method is implemented by a model of the concept Kernel:

```
namespace CGAL {
  namespace Shape_detection {
  /*!
[...]
    \tparam Gt must be a model of the concept `Kernel` with `Gt::FT` being `float` or `double`.
[...]
typedef typename Gt::Construct_point_on_3 Construct_point_on_3;
    Construct_point_on_3 construct_point_on_3_object() const
    { return m_gt.construct_point_on_3_object(); }
```

But I fail to dig deeper to find what I am looking for. How can I find the correct place in the code?

I tried to use my IDE to let me guide to the place where the actual calcuation happens, but it could not find the declartion to got to for `m_traits.construct_point_on_3_object()(l, 0);` in `Cylinder.h`
m_traits is of type Traits which is a template parameter for Shape_base class. I use the traits from the example in the [documentation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Shape_detection/index.html#title6) which is

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel     Kernel;
typedef std::vector<Point_with_normal>                          Pwn_vector;
typedef CGAL::First_of_pair_property_map<Point_with_normal>     Point_map;
typedef CGAL::Second_of_pair_property_map<Point_with_normal>    Normal_map;
typedef CGAL::Shape_detection::Efficient_RANSAC_traits
        <Kernel, Pwn_vector, Point_map, Normal_map>             Traits;
```

But I don't know how to continue from there. I searched the github repo, but that didn't help too much either, unfortunately.

Comment: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/04b5104b5b95c597250dbe74d708e6e9ab4e80db/Kernel_23/include/CGAL/Kernel/function_objects.h#L2190 https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/04b5104b5b95c597250dbe74d708e6e9ab4e80db/Cartesian_kernel/include/CGAL/Cartesian/Line_3.h#L117 Why do you want to know?

Comment: @MarcGlisse For my calculation, I need a support vector that is a good representation of the matching points (if you projected those points onto the axis, the support vector should lie within the range of the projections). It seems like CGAL does this anyway, so that I don't actually need to do it, but I have to confirm my guess.

I still struggle to see the solution, does `rep()` or `point()` somehow relate to how the line was created (like, reusing the support vector if given at construction time)?

Comment: If you construct a line from a point and a vector, then point() and to_vector() gives you those back.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I see, that's good to know and already helps me. I will try to find how the cylinders gets constructed in the shape detection process, do you happen to know where this can be found in the code?